# Python scope/object life

Tags: python

In the case of this code, is the object storing `k` being created and deleted each iteration through the loop? I would think it is, and so I typically declare the any such variables above a loop.

```
while (1):
    k = randint(0,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object being created and *discarded* each iteration is the `int` and that process is not affected by naming something `k` before the loop.  I also think that the object/name `k` is *created* once on the first iteration then is reassigned on subsequent iterations - it doesn't get discarded during the iteration.

[Python has names not variables](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

[Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a new object is being created each iteration. As for deletion, it is implementation-specific. CPython, for instance, uses reference counting and will delete the `k` when it reaches the end of the loop body. In other implementations, these objects may be cleared in batches by the garbage collector. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become unreachable they may be garbage-collected. An implementation is allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether — it is a matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still reachable.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to collect garbage containing circular references. See the documentation of the `gc` module for information on controlling the collection of cyclic garbage. Other implementations act differently and CPython may change. Do not depend on immediate finalization of objects when they become unreachable (ex: always close files).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `id`:

```
>>> while True:
...     k = randint(1, 100)
...     print id(k)
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
140348572606072
140348572604112
140348572604600
140348572604912
^C
>>>
```

This shows that `k` is being created each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as pointed out previously, a new variable is instantiated on each loop.  The root of your question, however, states that:

> I would think it is, and so I typically declare the any such variables
>   above a loop.

I just want to point out that such pre-initialization makes no difference on timing.  In fact, it would be slightly slower because it has to pre-assign the variable before over-writing it.

```
%%timeit
k = 0
for k in range(1000):
    k = randint(0, 10)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

%%timeit
for k in range(1000):
    k = randint(0, 10)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```